# Why wont this div center vertically using relative positioning?

Tags: html, css

Hey so I have this `div` and inside the `div` I have a `button`. I wanted to center the `div` horizontally and vertically. Also I wanted to center the `button` horizontally and vertically inside the `div`. Here is my code.

```html
<div style='position: relative; left: calc(50% - 250px); top: calc(50% - 100px); border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 200px;'>
  <button style='position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 30px; left: calc(50% - 50px); top: calc(50% - 15px);'>
    Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

The button positioning works fine inside the div. However I am curious why the div will center horizontally but not vertically? I am assuming it has something to do with the `position: relative`? But I am not sure.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the DIV doesn't have a reference for its relative height (percentage) - the parent element - in this case `body` - doesn't have a set height. Add this rule and it will center as desired:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style='position: relative; left: calc(50% - 250px); top: calc(50% - 100px); border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 200px;'>
  <button style='position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 30px; left: calc(50% - 50px); top: calc(50% - 15px);'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tend to prefer to use `100vh` these days, as opposed to percentages for heights.... percentages tend to break down when used within nested elements (clearly not the case here, but in other more complex cases)